# Shortcut keys for java or eclipse notes

Tags: java, eclipse, computer-science, shortcut, short

Hello I needed to know how do I uncomment out code in eclipse? I know <kbd>Crtl+Shift+C</kbd> will comment out a set of code how do I undo that?

Comment: Use it again. It's a toggle action.

Comment: in netbeans at least it's the same combination for both actions

Answer (score 0):

Here You have all shortcuts for Eclipse:
http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html

As You can see on point 7, its `Ctrl + Shift + \`.

Answer (score 0):

As Already said, It is the same shortcut to comment and uncomment.

I Would like to precise the most important, IMHO,  shortcut in Eclipse : `ctrl + shift + l` which lists all the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

To comment any code, select it and press <kbd>Ctrl + 7</kbd>.
Use again to undo.